# Nodejs Express 4 Routing Questin

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to prepend a NodeJS request through express to include /api/v1.  If I make an addition like to to my server.js file:

```
app.all('/Employees', require('./routes/Employees'));
```

I am able to go forward to localhost/Employees and get the proper response (it comes back from the javascript I have written in ./routes/Employees)

If I add /api/v1/ to the beginning of the app.all call, like so:

```
app.all('/api/*', requireAuthentication);
```

I am not able to go forward to localhost/api/v1/Employees.  The express manual even has an explicit note about this:

> Another example is white-listed "global" functionality. The example is much like before, however it only restricts paths that start with "/api":

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All request starting with `/api/*` will be passed to the function `requireAuthentication`  so your problem is within that function not handling the `/api/v1/Employees`

Answer (score 0):

Your app gets confused whenever request is received at /api/* -- it doesn't know where to go and what to do now.

If you want to prefix /api/v1 for your requests, you can do it with couple of ways - Choose what best suits your in your case:

[Mountpath](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.mountpath) way -

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
api = express();

api.all('/employees', function(req, res){
    console.log("url :: " + api.mountpath);
    res.send('hit at employess');
});

//you can do this here fo v(n)
app.use('/api/v1', api);

app.listen(3000);
```

other way -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('/employees', function(req, res){
    res.send('/employe');
});
app.use('/api/v1', function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect(req.path);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Happy Helping!